Why isn't my service's data shared between my Angular components?
I created a service DataAccessService:
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class DataAccessService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  @Output() queryParamsChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  _queryParams: any = null;

  set queryParams(value: any) {
    this._queryParams = value;
    this.queryParamsChange.emit(this._queryParams);
  }

  get queryParams(): any {
    return this._queryParams;
  }

and I use it in three components :
app-root and app-home and app-study,
I injected this service in constructor like this:
App component:
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  ...
  constructor(
    private dataService: DataAccessService,
    private router: Router,
  ) {
  ...
  } 

Study Component:
export class StudiesComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  routeNames: string[] = ['studies.toolbar.routeName'];
  queryParamsChange: Subscription;

  constructor(private dataService: DataAccessService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('ON_INIT StudiesComponent');
    console.log(
      'queryParams : ' + JSON.stringify(this.dataService._queryParams)
    );

Home Component:
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  ...
  constructor(
    private dataService: DataAccessService,
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  onClick(route: string, value: any): void {
    console.log(value);
    this.dataService.queryParams = value;
    this.router.navigate([route]);
  }

when I click, value is sent to service, I logged the value and it works.
and onClick function navigate to study page, and then, in onInit of StudiesComponent this.dataService.queryParams return Null.
I don't understand why.
Thanks for yours answers.
It explained in the subject.
Informations added:
I'm use Angular 17.3.6
My components are standalone.
I'm provide DataAccessService in app.config.ts as and once  :
    export const appProviders = [
      provideRouter(routes),
      provideHttpClient(),
      provideAnimations(),
      importProvidersFrom(
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
          defaultLanguage: 'fr',
          loader: {
            provide: TranslateLoader,
            useFactory: createTranslateLoader,
            deps: [HttpClient],
          },
        }),
        KeycloakAngularModule,
        HttpClientModule
      ),
      { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: environment.baseHref },
      { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'fr' },
      {
        provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
        useClass: CacheInterceptor,
        multi: true,
      },
      {
        provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
        useFactory: initializeKeycloak,
        multi: true,
        deps: [KeycloakService],
      },
      { provide: AuthService, deps: [KeycloakService] },
      KeycloakService,
      DataAccessService,
    ];

    export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
      providers: appProviders,
    };

I created a new component Test :
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataAccessService } from '../services/data-access.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrl: './test.component.scss',
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private dataService: DataAccessService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('ON_INIT TestComponent');
    const queryParams = this.dataService.queryParams;
    console.log('queryParams : ' + JSON.stringify(queryParams));
  }
}


do you have DataAccessService  added to any providers array, remove that!

I see, but no, I didn't add DataAccessService in providers array in my components. Otherwise, service would be instancied for each component.

please share the logs, also check if its reproducible on this stackblitz

@STEPHANE Where is DataAccessService provided? Once in app module? in different modules? Are your components standalone? Are they all under the same module? What version of Angular?

@Benny, I'm use Angular 17.3.6, DataAccessService is provided in app.config.ts

@STEPHANE see https://stackblitz.com/edit/shared-value-in-service?file=src%2Fmain.ts where I created a simple project similar to yours that seems to work well. Take a look and compare. Maybe you'll find something that I did differently. Focus on the service - where it's provided.

@Benny, thanks for your time, implication. I created a new component Test and it works.

See above. I'm sorry to say that I've made a migration of my old components to standalone components. Perhaps, this is a source of my problems.

@STEPHANE glad you sorted it out.

In StudiesComponent you are not actually subscribing to the EventEmitter, you are reading out the value of _queryParams, which at the time of initializing is specifically set to null in your DataAccessService.
Instead you want your StudiesComponent to subscribe to the EventEmitter and listen to the value it emits.
See below:
export class StudiesComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    routeNames: string[] = ['studies.toolbar.routeName'];
    queryParamsChange: Subscription;

    constructor(private dataService: DataAccessService) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        console.log('ON_INIT StudiesComponent');

        this.dataService.queryParamsChange
            .subscribe(queryParams => { 
                console.log('queryParams : ' + JSON.stringify(queryParams)
            })
    }
}

Also see https://v17.angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter#subscribe for more information.
